# Remove text between first and last brakets

Tags: javascript

My original string :

```
[Abc ![](https://i.imgur.com/5AteeJf.png)](https://quiz.com?/quiz_id=2/quiz_name=15/level=null)
```

i tried with this javascript formula but no luck

```
string.replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/, '')
```

How can i remove string between first [ and last ]?

Thank you so much

My desired output is url

```
https://quiz.com?/quiz_id=2/quiz_name=15/level=null
```

Comment: are you writing a markdown parser?

Comment: @DanielA.White you're right

Comment: you could use string.split("]")

Comment: Why doesn't the desired output include the `()`? You said you only want to remove the string between square brackets, nothing about removing parentheses.

Comment: Why are you writing your own markdown parser? I'll bet there's already one (like the one that SE uses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.*` instead of `[^\]]*`, so the match won't stop at the first `]`.

```js
let string = '[Abc ![](https://i.imgur.com/5AteeJf.png)](https://quiz.com?/quiz_id=2/quiz_name=15/level=null)';
let result = string.replace(/\[.*\]/, '');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` method with `/\[.*?\]\((.*)\)/` regex. to get the `text` after opening and closing the square bracket and between parenthesis.

```js
const str = '[Abc ![](https://i.imgur.com/5AteeJf.png)](https://quiz.com?/quiz_id=2/quiz_name=15/level=null)'

const [_, value] = str.match(/\[.*\]\((.*)\)/);

console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you were using was using only up to the first ']'. This regular expression should do it:

[.*]

```
let sentence = "[Abc ![](https://i.imgur.com/5AteeJf.png)](https://quiz.com?/quiz_id=2/quiz_name=15/level=null)";
let extractedSentence = sentence.replace(/\[.*\]/, "");
```